# Qt c++ how to free memory after loading a new HTML page

Tags: html, c++, qt, ram

I'am doing a Qt app in c++ with frontend in Html / Css.

Each time i load a new html page (or if i reload one), the app get +5mo ram, and dont get free after quit. (So after 10 pages i got +50mo ram)

I've allready try to préload my pages into a vector, but the loading still add 5mo each time.
I've also think to load pages in threads, so they'll be destroyed after using.
Is it a possible solution to keep a descent ram weight??

As i'am a newbie i'am probably doing something stupid : here's my code for loading a new view :

```
Q_INVOKABLE bool                myBridge::newView(QString page)
{
    QString                         path = ("file:///" + QDir::currentPath() + "/");

    if (!(page.compare("page3.html")))
        _mediaPlayer->setTimer(10000);
    else
        _mediaPlayer->setTimer(60000);
    _view->close();
    _view = new WebView;
    _view->load(QUrl(path + page));
    _view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("bridge", this);
    _view->showFullScreen();
    _mediaPlayer->_srnsaver->timerRestart();
    return (true);
}
```

Can you see something wrong in this code?

Comment: You create a new `WebView` in the function, but you never seem to be deleting the old one?

Comment: i'll try to put _view in TMPview to laod my new page and delete the old

Comment: Initialize `_view` to `nullptr` (or `0` or `NULL`) and just call do `delete` before doing `new`. Oh, and *check* for the null pointer before trying to dereference the pointer by calling `_view->close()`.

Comment: Initialize _view to nullptr didnt help me for the +5mo :/

_view->close();
_view = nullptr;
delete _view;
_view = new WebView;

Comment: Ho an btw, _view is never NULL

Answer (score 0):

Every time this method is called you create a new `WebView` and you most likely never delete the previous one. Naturally this will cause a memory leak since nothing is freed. Calling `close()` does not delete the object.

Comment: Delete cause me a sigsegv :/

Comment: You need to `delete` the previous webviev. And if you call `close()` or delete on a NULL pointer (or uninitialized), since you're not even checking if `_view` points somewhere, you will get sigsegv.

Comment: @EtienneCtrs Are you initializing `_view` to NULL in the beginning to make sure it doesn't point to random place in memory?

Comment: I use "new" a the begining for view, as i know its not NULL? No?

But ill try that ty

Comment: @EtienneCtrs Before calling this method? Then it is initialized and deleting it shouldn't cause issues. But if only in this method, you are calling `close()` and `delete` before `new`.

Comment: Yeah, at the start of my application i set _view to "mainpage.html" and always load "mainpage" if i quit